# How can I make videos play like youtube in my site? html/css (read more)

Tags: html, css, web, youtube, video-streaming

I have a site (for a band) that I am working on, here: http://atfa.hostei.com/.

On the videos page it shows an intro video, and then you are redirected to their live stream page where you can watch their concerts live. Underneath the intro video, I have a chat room. Under the chat room is where I want to post all of their YouTube videos, updates, etc.

I've been trying to figure out how to do it through trial and error but I am lost. I want to have the YouTube video player, but then there will be other video thumbnails that when you click them it will change the video ON your page.

But also I don't want too many videos so I want to make a little tab underneath the says 1 2 3... 8 so you can open different videos while staying ON the same page without refreshing or anything.

An example of what I am after would be on the VIDEOS page here: http://www.higatv.com/rhtv/?page_id=142

I've viewed the source but I'm lost.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking 10 questions at once. And have you never heard of line breaks?

Answer (score 2):

My advice to you is get one feature working then move to the next.  Don't try to implement three different thing you are not familiar with.

---

A simple example to get you started.

1) Get all the videos for a user\channel or you can do an rss feed to check the list and parse it based on that

or you can do http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author= then parse the info

or you can put them manually.

2) Use pagination to seperate them in different pages.  Something like http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/11/17/jpaginate-a-fancy-jquery-pagination-plugin/

3) A placeholder for the video

```
     <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/2pROe-xq2vo?rel=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0&amp;egm=0&amp;border=0&amp;fs=1&amp;showinfo=0" style="width: 425px; height: 350px">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/2pROe-xq2vo?rel=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0&amp;egm=0&amp;border=0&amp;fs=1&amp;showinfo=0">
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
      </object>
```

4) onclick change the video url `<param name="movie"` or just delete the old object and create another one.

**Edit:**

Example for step (4) is here http://jsfiddle.net/794Re/3/

There are two ways to embed the video.  I like the iframe one it seems simple.

**Edit:**

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/zK4Z8/1/

The trick to get the thumbnail is to put the video id `<img  src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/VideoIdGoesHere/default.jpg" width="120" height="90" />`

Then to load a video you basically change the movie param and the data attribute like in the function `loadVideoById(videoId)`

```
<a id="img1" onclick="load(this);"  rel="2yoKjhxXVN8" style="margin-left: 41px; ">
  <img  src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/2yoKjhxXVN8/default.jpg" width="120" height="90" />
</a>

function load(element) {
    var videoId = $("#" + element.id).attr("rel");
    $('#movieObj').remove();
     $(loadVideoById(videoId)).prependTo('#vholder');
}

function loadVideoById(videoId) {
    return '<object id="movieObj" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/' + videoId + '?rel=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0&amp;egm=0&amp;border=0&amp;fs=1&amp;showinfo=0" style="width: 425px; height: 350px"><param name="wmode" value="transparent"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/' + videoId + '?rel=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0&amp;egm=0&amp;border=0&amp;fs=1&amp;showinfo=0"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"></object>';
}
```

Comment: What excactly do you mean on the last step 4)

Comment: Now, how excactly do I make it so when I click the thumbnails that they appear in place of the other video?